# Sum up numbers close to a specific number in a list

Tags: python, list, sum

Example 1

```
List = [12,40,30,53,82,31,100]
```

I want to produce a list which includes so many numbers close to 80 and not larger than 80 . If the number originally larger than 80 just pass.

The result like `[52,30, ,53,82, 31,100]`
Because of `[12+40,30,53,82,31 ,100]`

Example 2

```
List =[45,102,31,25,2,99]
Result = [45,102,58,99]
```

Please help me figure out how to code with this question, really appreciate it.

I have tried

```
For i in range(len(List)):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start = -1
sum_ = 0
List = [45,102,31,25,2,99]
result = []
i = 0

while i < len(List):
    if start == -1:
        start = i

    new_sum = sum_ + List[i]
    if new_sum > 80:
        result.append(sum_)
        start = -1
        sum_ = 0
        new_sum = 0
        if List[i] > 80:
            result.append(List[i])
            i += 1
        continue
    else:
        sum_ = new_sum
        i += 1

print(result)
# [45, 102, 58, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define simple generator function which will yield sum of values if they reached limit:

```py
def sum_up_to(source, limit):
    summ = 0
    for i in source:
        if summ + i > limit:
            if summ:
                yield summ
                summ = i
            else:
                yield i
        else:
            summ += i
    if summ:
        yield summ
```

Then just call it with any limit:

```py
src1 = [12, 40, 30, 53, 82, 31, 100]
dst1 = list(sum_up_to(src1, 80))  # [52, 30, 53, 82, 31, 100]
src2 = [45, 102, 31, 25, 2, 99]
dst2 = list(sum_up_to(src2, 80))  # [45, 102, 58, 99]
```

---

**Upd.** I've made some tests *([code](https://tio.run/##nVTtjqowEP3vUzT8WciyCiu7smbxRYxperVK74WWlLJmn947bfkUNOs2McJ8nDmcmU7xrVLBl3EhL5dSVHJPccZKhRK0DV99FAU@WsLvbemjGN6XoY/CINjNZgd6RCL7YhxLcUqVa5N9lLGcKW89Q3Acx0GpUkW5XixKRfb/xBeVx0yc53uRL8ji/ePjPVrF0SIM4tcoClY6w2SWVZ4Dh8C8HIVEDDGObA2LrQ872sBncG9s5c7ZCxga9flmNDsY38hVl2YDB81KegulixxHWXoN2ohOj4YRdJ8SfpCkIBkuGT@ltaqPyBkHy7GckpZVZpoKnRtIKgk/URc6nFHeVPOGChvjlu3QJkFxgCBTx1pIDyXQpeE3W8@cFAXlB7dN93oyAayN2r6EO2hfV@NT15jCs5FJF3pH9ZsMajFUJXkdVOtOCkVglJUUfwn/heqr8G1iiBWRWvSXsJlp3M50vyNGaOMxj@eUZRQMn/2eDFtigTXy1bjVFdmsNXN6xlAZjKb@84SAgNhEbW6o32oJGN5kyfoje4PffeyYSzC6pt2UjSj8aKhaLD0kQy57wRXjFb1/TzXdmuBsAnBqdIA3xpzkFGPdjSeMcz1F@MmCs7wQoI1iOWXKAhSSceU6vcW5dvw6Ym7/3La6ozexO16yZkPDPg48z/Hb6BK4FYlzlCJHDZGGQg/DRz2QXjqv8j9UJrDc4Rir5/UpX6@me7xvrDFT8qeUrzF@zXtwte@ynloCj3EeIDzE@HL5Dw))* to compare solutions from all answers. Here is results *(lower is better)*:

```
olvin_roght: 0.263744345
chandrapal_singh: 0.39295867199999995
captain_trojan: 0.605765677
```

Tests shown that solution from this answer demonstrates best performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
List =[45,102,31,25,2,99]
# List = [12,40,30,53,82,31,100]
result = []

for i in range(0,len(List)):
    if List[i]>=80 or len(result)==0:
        result.append(List[i])
    elif result[-1] + List[i] <=80 :
        result[-1] += List[i] 
    else :
        result.append(List[i])
    
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).